# website internal folder access redirect to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect to index.php of whichever directory is requested. how do i do that ?

```
js/
module/
lib/
data/
source/
theme/
```

example :

```
http://www.example.com/folder/
```

it should be redirect to like this

```
http://www.example.com/index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

but I'll prefer to keep one `index.php` file in all folder and put redirection to root folder `index.php`, because it will also redirect queries for files that exist, such as images, javascript files or style sheets files.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to redirect to **index.php of whichever directory is requested**. how do i do that ?

You mean something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/[^/]*$ /$1/index.php [L]
```

So if you request `/js/something` you get routed to `/js/index.php`, or if you request `/module/something` you get routed to `/module/index.php`.

---

EDIT

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/ /index.php [L]
```

Change the fag to `[L,R]` if you want to redirect the browser.

Comment: i mean if someone try to access internal folders

/js/
/modules/

they should redirect to root index.php. which mean website home page.

Comment: @harsha500 that's not what you said *at all* in your question. See the edit